# F4 search help based on a structure. How does it work?

Tags: abap, sap-gui

I've recently been taking closer look at the Function Module 'F4IF_FIELD_VALUE_REQUEST' and saw that you can pass a table, but also a structure to the Parameter 'TABNAME'. When you pass a table name, the F4 help will obviously present entries of said DB-table, giving you the possibility to choose one of them as a value for your parameter. But how does it work if you pass the name of a structure? Since the structure is only a Datatype it doesn't contain any Data itself. Where is the Data I see in the F4-Help coming from then?

thanks in advance,

Jellyfish

Comment: You say "obviously present entries of said DB-table", but no, that's generally wrong. It takes both TABNAME and FIELDNAME, goes into the ABAP Dictionary, and takes the search help defined at the concerned field, or at the data element level, or at the domain level, etc. The parameter TABNAME can even be a data element name. In the end, it's impossible to answer your question precisely (that would imply to explain all the possibilities, and it would take a lot of time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you pass a table name, the F4 help will obviously present entries of said DB-table

No, not necessarily.

It will use the search help defined for that field in the dictionary definition of the database table / structure. You can see those in the transaction SE11 on the tab "Input Help/Check".

The search help for each field might be:

- Implemented with a check table, which is usually not the table you are looking at. See the column "check table" to see where the values come from.
- Implemented with fixed values. The possible values are taken from the domain of the data type.
- Implemented by a specialized picker for that data type (dates and times)
- Implemented by an explicit search help, which might:

  - use a table or view
  - use a search help exit, which is a function module which provides the data procedurally
  - or both: The function module receives data from the database and can then process it before it is shown to the user

Comment: thanks for your answers and comments. I've gained deeper understanding now.